# OS X / Finder - Right Click “New Folder with Selection” - how to Increase the Animation Effect Speed?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

10.9.x Finder

The effect that pulls all the selected items into a new folder from the right click **"New Folder with Selection"** is really nice, but way too slow for me.

Anyone know a terminal command that would increase the animation rate?